# MS Access Master/Detail Form Child Link Show all

Tags: ms-access, master-detail, subforms

OK.  So not sure how to correctly ask this question to find the right solution.

I have a database setup with a Primary Key which is a text field.  This key links to the code in additional tables in the database.

I then setup a query with a union that combines all of the various tables into a single location.

This location is tied to the subform in my form.  My Master form has a combo box which prefills with the primary key from the first table.  This filters based on what is chosen and updates the subform.

What I want is a choice in the dropdown which is equivalent to ALL.  I tried using an asterisk (*) as the primary key but that didn't return any results.

I am sure this has to be possible in some way but just not sure how to go about it.

Does anyone have any insight?  Thanks much for your time.

Comment: Do you also need to use multi-select with your combobox? I have done what you are looking for by using VBA to create the sql or apply a filter.

Comment: That did it. I had to remove the master/child link which wouldn't allow it to show all results then using VBA to create the filter worked great!  Thanks!